# Appium: Not able to locate application back button

Tags: python-appium

My application is build up on flutter framework. I testing with python code. Where I am not able to locate application back button element.

Here is my xpath for back button

```
self.appium_driver.find_element(AppiumBy.XPATH, "//android.view.View[@content-desc='Back']").click()
```

and tried with touch actions

```
TouchAction(self.appium_driver).tap(self.appium_driver.find_element(AppiumBy.XPATH,
self.loc_password_screen.get("back"))).perform()
```

Here is the element in inspector

[inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEn3y.png)

I am not getting any error also. Can any one suggest a way out.
Thanks in advance!